# How can I remove borders from ListView (or TableView)?

Tags: java, css, javafx

The problem is in grey line at borders of ListView. I had set border-color transparent, but it does not work. If I set border-color black it just paints on the top of grey line.

[image]

```css
.root {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}

#wordsList {        
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}
```

Here is my FXML code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import h.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Tab xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
     xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" closable="false">
    <text><Constants fx:constant="SECOND_TAB_NAME"/></text>
    <HBox>
        <ListView fx:id="wordsList" prefWidth="250">        
        </ListView>
    </HBox>
</Tab>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting it to white?

Comment: I don't know how to set this to white or smth, because property .list-view -fx-border-color does not work. I can't find property name to set color of this.

Comment: You need to setting this property when your list is empty or when you add items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In default `modena.css` ListView does not have border property but two background colors with insets.

**Modena.css**

```
.list-view {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
    -fx-padding: 1;
}
```

Replace `-fx-box-border` with your desired color(white or transparent) to remove border.